How can I reset Flutter App State Upon Logout?
I'm using Flutter with flutter_riverpod, go_router, and secure_flutter_storage. While I've successfully cleared local storage upon logout, the app retains previous settings and content upon logging back in. How can I reset the app's state to ensure a fresh start on subsequent logins?

  void logout() async {
    final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

    try {
      // Delete all data from the secure storage
      await storage.deleteAll();
      state = AuthState(isLoggedIn: false);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error from logout function: $e');
    }
  }

here's how I am calling this function
  _buildLogoutOption(context, () {
    ref.read(authStateNotifierProvider.notifier).logout();
    context.go('/welcome');
            }),



try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix

Can you ensure that await storage.deleteAll(); is successfully completed?

@AhmedElghandour It does clear the storage, the problem is with the state.

@VinamraJaiswal I tried the package but I am getting some errors.
Exception caught by widgets library
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4442 pos 12: 'element._lifecycleState == _ElementLifecycle.inactive': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Exception caught by widgets library
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
flutter: Exception caught by widgets library
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 2115 pos 12: '_elements.contains(element)': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was:

would you try ref.invalidate(Provider); ?

Try with:
ref.invalidate(someProvider);

On the other hand you can listen the invalidate event using:
ref.onDispose(myCloseCallback);

